# How to change the jquery UI dialog button position on top of form?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to change the button position to top of the page ? I have tried soo many examples, but those are only displaying in left ot right.but i want to display the button on top of the form .

```
      $( "#popup" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({ 
 autoOpen: false,
 height: 300,
 width: 350,
 modal: true,
 buttons : {
 "search" : function(){
 $(this).css({position:top})
 },
 "use selected" : function(){}
 }

 });
```

Comment: May be chances are there ?

Comment: [Please see this illustration in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UjYG/) - Sorry, I was feeling too spunky. The simple solution is to target the buttonset of the dialog and change it's position, and give it a top offset value.

Comment: Wow..Great.Datatable also we can display in the same form ?

Comment: Your english reminds me of Yoda from star wars. I'm having difficulty understanding your needs. If you're trying to use a `jQuery Datatable Plugin` within a `jQuery Dialog Window` that's fine. You'll probably need to do some testing until you find the right way for it to work, hard to advise on such a broad question.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to prepend the button element position while opening dialog , just like the code snippet below

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
  open: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).prepend($(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane'));
  },
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Cliff's answer but I would use `.before()` instead of `.prepend()` as this will keep your buttonpane and content elements at the same level.

```
$('#dialog-form').dialog({
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).before($(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane'));
    },
    ...
```

I would also then change the border of the button pane. (depends on your theme)

Css

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    border-top-width:0px; border-bottom-width:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abduncan/Fjkkr/)

Essentially, your CSS:

```
div.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    position: absolute;
    /* height + padding + margin of header */
    top: 41px;
    /* play around with this setting to your liking. */
    width: 97%;
    /* use a more specific selector to avoid using !important */
    padding: 0 !important;
}
/* for a bottom border use this */
div.ui-dialog-buttonpane {
    /* use a more specific selector to avoid using !important */
    border-width: 0 0 1px 0 !important;
}
```